# How can I copy row values based on the value of one of the cells in that row?

Tags: excel, google-docs

Column A consists of a series of dates extending from today into the future.

Columns B-E are other values corresponding to those dates.

Initially the first three rows were blank. Then I used the function TODAY() to obtain today's date and put that in cell A1. Today's date matches a value in cell A91. I now want the values in B1-E1 to match the values in B91-E91.

How can I go about doing that? It needs to be done with reference to cell A1 because I want it to update whenever the spreadsheet is opened. Thus I can't just type =B91 in B1.

Here's what it looks like

[image]

I am working in Google Spreadsheets but I suspect an answer related to Microsoft Excel would probably work here too.

Comment: Have you tried using the VLOOKUP formula? If so, where is it going wrong?

Comment: I considered this but I believe VLOOKUP just returns the value of a cell matching some search criteria. I did not see how it could be used in this context.

Comment: No, VLOOKUP with the last optional parameter set to `FALSE` returns the value from a cell offset by the number of columns to the right of the cell where the exact match of looked up value is found. Specify the column offset in the third parameter.

Comment: Cool. I got it worked out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VLOOKUP function works, for example

=VLOOKUP(A1,$A$3:$E$1000,2,FALSE)

Comment: It's good you got it. You should accept your answer to close the question.

Comment: Thanks, and will do. However, the site will not allow me to do that for two days.